# Trigger issue showing missing ;

Tags: oracle, if-statement, plsql

I've been stuck on this problem for days and have no idea why this is compiling with errors. The error is missing ; at line **":NEW.desc:= concat(:NEW.desc, 'Paul dollar');"**, Can anyone see where I'm going wrong here? or even point me in the right direction would be awesome.

```
CREATE TRIGGER trig_name
before INSERT ON table_name for each row
BEGIN 
    IF(:NEW.name= 'John') THEN 
        :NEW.bank_bal := :NEW.bank_bal - .10;
        :NEW.desc:= concat(:NEW.desc, 'John ten');
    ENDIF;
     IF(:NEW.name= 'Jane') THEN 
        :NEW.bank_bal := :NEW.bank_bal - .20;
        :NEW.desc:= concat(:NEW.desc, 'Jane twenty');
    ENDIF;
     IF (:NEW.name= 'Ron') THEN 
        :NEW.bank_bal := :NEW.bank_bal - .20;
        :NEW.desc:= concat(:NEW.desc, 'Ron twenty');
    ENDIF;
     IF (:NEW.name= 'Paul') THEN 
        :NEW.bank_bal := :NEW.bank_bal - 1;
        :NEW.desc:= concat(:NEW.desc, 'Paul dollar');
    ENDIF;    
END; 
/
```

Comment: `DESC` is a SQL keyword and an Oracle reserved word.  You should name the column something else.

Comment: Did you create the `DESC` column as **quoted identified** using **double quotation marks**? If yes, then you must use the double quotation amrks every time you refer the column name.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

> ENDIF;

in oracle it is not one word

```
IF condition THEN
   {...statements to execute when condition is TRUE...}
END IF;
```

Comment: Thank you thank you thank you!! you have saved the remainder of my hair. :)